# How to get particular key values in using Lodash

Tags: javascript, parsing, lodash

I have array of objects like following.

```
[{
  "key": "remember_tip",
  "description": "some remember description"
}, {
  "key": "logout_tip",
  "description": "some logout description"
}, {
  "key": "notremember_tip",
  "description": "some not remember description"
},{
  "key": "backgroundOff",
  "description": "some backgroundOff description"
},
{
   "key": "backgroundOn",
      "description": "some backgroundOn description"
    },
 ..];
```

I have methods like following.

```
someMethod = (variable) => {

  if (variable === remember) {
    this.rememberHandler()
  } else if (variable === logout) {
    this.logoutHandler()
  } else if (variable === notremember) {
    this.notrememberHandler()
  }else if (variable === backgroundoff) {
    this.backgroundoffHandler()
  }

}

rememberHandler = () => {
  //showpopup with remember_tip description
}

logoutHandler = () => {
  //showpopup with logout_tip description
}

notrememberHandler = () => {
  //showpopup with notremember_tip description
}
    backgroundoffHandler = () => {
  //showpopup with backgroundOff description
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the current structure to get the description values. Use `_.find()` to get the object, with the requested key, and get the value with `_.get()`:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, find, get } = _

const getFrom = arr => flow(
  key => find(arr, { key }),
  pr(get, 'description'),
)

const tips = [{
  "key": "remember_tip",
  "description": "some remember description"
}, {
  "key": "logout_tip",
  "description": "some logout description"
}, {
  "key": "notremember_tip",
  "description": "some not remember description"
}]

const getFromTips = getFrom(tips)

const result = getFromTips('remember_tip')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.14/lodash.js"></script>
```

However, this is a lot of code for something quite simple. Create a Map of key to description from the array. When the `show` method is called, it gets the `description` from the Map, and displays the popup:

```js
const tips = [{
    "key": "remember_tip",
    "description": "some remember description"
  }, {
    "key": "logout_tip",
    "description": "some logout description"
  }, {
    "key": "notremember_tip",
    "description": "some not remember description"
  }, {
    "key": "backgroundOff",
    "description": "some backgroundOff description"
  },
  {
    "key": "backgroundOn",
    "description": "some backgroundOn description"
  }
];

const tipsMap = new Map(tips.map(({ key, description }) => [key, description]))

const showpopup = console.log // demo show popup

const show = popUp => {
  const description = tipsMap.get(popUp);

  if (description) showpopup(description)
}

show('logout_tip')

show('backgroundOff')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I used first method, But, Getting following error undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0, _lodash.pr)(_lodash.get, 'description')')

Comment: please check my comment and updated array of data too.

Comment: I've used destructuring with alias to assign `_.partialRight()` to `pr`. You can use `_.partialRight()` directly. The data doesn't actually change the answer, but it makes the 2nd solution less fitting for you.

Comment: Can you post final solution which is suitable for my use case if possible?

Comment: You're welcome. The 2nd solution transform the data to a Map more suitable to your case (as far as I can see from the question). However, if the 1st answer works for you, use it.

Comment: Can we use only find and get to achieve this instead of flow, partialright? But, Your second solution is little confusing, Please check my array data keys once.

Comment: You can use `const getFrom = (arr, key) => find(arr, { key })`, and get the description afterwards. The 2nd solution converts the array to a Map, 

but it might not fit your case.

Comment: I did not get you

Comment: What didn't you get?

Comment: We can call like this,     const getFromTips = find(arr, 'key'); and then we can call, description, Right? and 2nd solution is not suitable?

Comment: Yep for the 1st part `const getFrom = (arr, key) => find(arr, { key })`. The 2nd solution uses a static Map, but if your data changes, you'll need to recreate the Map every time, so it might not be a good fit for your case.

Comment: Do we need to use this completely? const getFrom = (arr, key) => find(arr, { key }) or  const getFromTips = find(arr, 'key'); is enough?

Comment: The `find` method needs the array and key. If you don't want to wrap it with a function, use - `tip = find(arr, { key })` directly in your code.

Comment: const getFromTips = find(arr, 'key');
    const toolTipText = get(getFromTips, 'text'); // here where we can pass particular tool_tip? Same data getting for all popups

Comment: I suggest that you open a new question.